# How to create MSK Cluster configuration with Cloud Formation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-msk, amazon-msk

I'm creating MSK with Cloud Formation.
By the way, I can't find how to create MSK Cluster configuration, in Cloud Formation documents.

So how can I create MSK Cluster configuration with Cloud Formation or
do I can't create MSK Cluster configuration with Cloud Formation?

If there are some references about that, please answer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using regular CloudFormation resources. See [here](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/647) for an open feature request to add it.

There are however still options if you want to provision this using CloudFormation, for example:

- Using a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html)
- Using an [Extension](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/registry.html), e.g. by [creating your own](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation-cli/latest/userguide/resource-types.html)

Both of these are, however, a lot more work than simply using a regular CloudFormation resource.